# If a new planet was discovered & became a spot of constant tourism, would that decrease car pollution and give the earth's climate time to heal

Tags: earth-like, earth

if a new planet was discovered and it was possible to live there and was not too far from earth, and after it was made suitable for human life and so on and became a spot of constant tourism, would that decrease the car pollution and give the ozone layer time to heal, or can the ozone layer even heal? note that the modern world problems such as the ozone layer wakening and car pollutions are constantly affecting the earth's climate.

Comment: If we have the technology to terraform another planet and make it habitable for human life, we'll just *terraform the earth*.

Comment: Could you explain why you think that this could be the case? I fail to see a connection. Also please tell us who is going to live there, travel distance, how you get there even and so on

Comment: I have written a meta question about such questions recently: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6769/questions-about-worlds-with-low-maturity-what-to-do-when-a-question-cannot-be if the people close- or down-voting have time to answer or comment, it might help the discussion.

Comment: Did the opening of Disneyland reduce global pollution?

Comment: Near by, in astronomical terms, is not near at all in human terms. A vacation troop to Alpha Centauri would take longer than the recorded history of the human race, traveling many times faster than a bullet.

Comment: I think what you actually meant to ask about is green house gasses and the global warming they cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This is a "frame challenge" answer.)

> would that decrease the car pollution and give the ozone layer time to heal, or can the ozone layer even heal?

Your question has two fundamental flaws:

1. Car pollution causes ozone depletion.
2. The ozone layer is not on the path to regeneration.

Neither of those are true.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion

> The main cause of ozone depletion and the ozone hole is manufactured chemicals, especially manufactured halocarbon refrigerants, solvents, propellants and foam-blowing agents (chlorofluorocarbons (CFCs), HCFCs, halons)

None of those chemicals are produced by vehicles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion#Prospects_of_ozone_depletion

> The Antarctic ozone hole is expected to continue for decades. Ozone concentrations in the lower stratosphere over Antarctica will increase by 5–10 percent by 2020 and return to pre-1980 levels by about 2060–2075. This is 10–25 years later than predicted in earlier assessments, because of revised estimates of atmospheric concentrations of ozone-depleting substances, including a larger predicted future usage in developing countries. Another factor that may prolong ozone depletion is the drawdown of nitrogen oxides from above the stratosphere due to changing wind patterns.[87] **A gradual trend toward "healing" was reported in 2016.**[9]

Comment: Also, perhaps pointing out that climate change due to `car pollutions` amongst other things, is not simply a function of tourism

Answer (score 4):

No not at the moment.

Firstly note that we don't actually need to worry about the ozone layer too much these days, the cause of that was cloroflorocarbons (CFC's) which have since been banned in most developed countries, the ozone layer is already healing.

That being said the rockets or space planes we would need to use to even get lots of humans into orbit would produce more pollution than those same humans simply continuing to use cars for the rest of their lives. (this is also ignoring how we get from our solar system to theirs, and simply considers even getting into orbit around earth first.) The net effect of that much tourism would likely be disastrous for the environment rather than good for it.

If a PORTAL was discovered to some habitable alien planet then that might help, but simply finding an alien planet nearby would not do.